# How do you automatically update service address used in lambda expression when you relaunch a service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito for user management in my app. I have set up a trigger that fires a Lambda function every time a user signs up. In the lambda function, an endpoint in my application gets called.

The problem is when I shut down and then relaunch my application, it gets a new address.

How do I set it up so that all my functions automatically update the addresses to work with the new instance address?

Comment: You don't have an ELB in front of the application? The service call is to the instance itself?

Comment: @RodrigoM for now, yes. I didn't think of an ELB But even so, the question would apply. For example, what if I change the ELB?

Comment: Well  that would be less common. ELBs are pretty static resource-wise - its the instances that come and go. ELBs are more or less fixed, by design. But yes, in the case of an ELB DNS name change, I would be using an alias like `app.example.com` for the ELB DNS name and replace the target ELB name at the time the ELB was replaced. TTL propagation times would still apply.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the technique I use to update the service address of an instance for the use case  you describe:

The key is to use Route 53 to publish the DNS host name of the service end point, EG app.example.com.  Your Lambda function should reference that URL, rather than the instance public DNS. Your instance must update this record each time it is initialized.

To do that, use an instance [user data script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), and dynamically update the hosted zone on [Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html) at instance launch time. For example, here is the section I use on an Ubuntu instance:

```
wget -q https://github.com/barnybug/cli53/releases/download/0.8.12/cli53-linux-amd64
mv cli53-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/cli53
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cli53
INSTANCE_IP_PRIVATE=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`
cli53 rrcreate --replace \"", {"Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "dns-PrivateHostedZoneId" }},"\" \"app 300 A ${INSTANCE_IP_PRIVATE}\"
```

Given zone `example.com`, the last line will create/update an `A` record with the current ip, for host name `app` with a `TTL` of 300.

A few notes:

1. Note line 1, where it downloads and install [cli53](https://github.com/barnybug/cli53), a command line tool for Amazon Route 53.  cli53 provides import and export from BIND format and simple command line management of Route 53 domains.  *You simply cannot do this operation as easily with the AWS CLI* - in 1 line! This is a well supported  utility and has been ported to many platforms.
2. The last part of the snippet is CloudFormation syntax used to reference the Route 53 host zone id.  If you are not using CloudFormation, use whatever works for you there.
3. Be aware of DNS record propagation times and TTL time.  [DNS changes takes less than a minute, and minimum TTL is 60 seconds](https://serverfault.com/questions/431853/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-route-53-cname-to-work).  There could be requests made during  this time frame that would resolve to the old ip.  An ELB is recommended here to prevent this issue. Or have the Lambda retry a few minutes as needed till it connects.
4. This snippet is updating a private hosted zone.  You would be using a public hosted zone. Same technique can be used to query for the public IP.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer